# get mousemove-X OR preventDefault-Y

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm working on a then and now image overlay script. it's working really well, except on mobile.... I've been working all day to try and get the user experience dead on, and it's been driving me crazy!

I've built a very simple script that lets you move the mouse or your finger across an image to see the image underneath it [full code below]

```
<style type="text/css">
    .trackMe img.packard {
        width:100% !important;
        top:0 !important;
        left:0 !important;
        position:absolute;
        margin:0 !important;
    }

    .trackMe img.now{
        width:100% !important;
        margin:0 !important;
    }
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var xpos = '';
    var ypos = '';
    $('.trackMe').each(function(){
        $(this).children("img:last").on("mousemove touchmove", function(e) {
            var currentY = e.originalEvent.touches ?  e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY : e.pageY;
            var currentX = e.originalEvent.touches ?  e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX;

            e.preventDefault();

            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var xpos = (currentX - offset.left);
            //now to get the first child image width..
            var thisImage = $(this);
            var thisWidth = thisImage.width();
            var pct = Math.round((xpos/thisWidth)*100)/100;
            var ipct = Math.abs(Math.round(((xpos-thisWidth)/thisWidth)*100)/100);
            thisImage.css({ 'opacity' : ipct });
        });
    });
});

</script>

<div style="position:relative; min-width:320px; height:auto; overflow:hidden;" class="trackMe">
    <img src="1a.jpg" class="now" />
    <img src="1b.jpg" class="packard" />
</div>
```

The only thing that's driving me crazy about this is, the e.preventdefault call prevents vertical scrolling on mobile if you press and image when you go to scroll. The two options I see for this come from either committing this trigger on the X specifically, or having a way to call e.preventdefault (Except for Y).

I'm pretty stuck on this one, but would really love to hear if anyone else has had to deal with this kind of issue!

Comment: is There a scroll bar? Is the user supposed to scrolls?

Comment: The user is supposed to scroll vertically on the page. The page is a list of 20+ images that run the then/now script. The problem is, since it's preventing the default action while scrolling over an image, the user has a harder time scrolling down to the rest of the images. That's why I'd like to either capture ONLY the hotizontal mouse/touch events, or prevent the default for everything by the Y(vertical) actions, which on mobile is scrolling.